# Trying to get a subset based on row and column of a matrix with C

Tags: c, matrix, subset, extract

For an assignment I'm trying to get a subset of a matrix based on a input of row and column.
below is my code so far it is meant to read in numbers from a text file of a nxm size which is determined by the user.

I don't know how to extract a smaller 2x2 matrix from the larger matrix based on row and column
e.g if the large matrix is :

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

9 1 2 3

4 5 6 7

and i wanted to extract starting from row 2 and column 3

i would want out

7 8

2 3

it is the end of the code (in the matrix determinant function) where i want it to be extracted and stored in a struct matrix which i created. The extracted matrix is to be consecutive from the starting point row and column the user picks

code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//creating a variable type for the matrix created
struct matrix
{
    char name;
    float mValues[10][10];
    int nrows;
    int ncols;
};

//Function declarations
void matrixInput(struct matrix *mat, FILE *in);
void matrixDisplay(struct matrix mat);
float matrixDeterminant(struct matrix m1, struct matrix *m2, int *check);

int main()
{
    FILE *fin; //fin = fopen("matrix.txt","r")
    struct matrix matA;
    struct matrix matB;
    float determinant;
    int i,j,flag;




    fin=fopen("matrix.txt","r");
    if (fin!=NULL)
    {
        printf("File was found!\n");
        matrixInput(&matA,fin);      //Function call to create matrix
        matrixDisplay(matA);         //Function call to display the created matrix
        determinant=matrixDeterminant(matA,&matB,&flag);

        matrixDisplay(matB);

    }
    else printf("File not found\n");
}

void matrixInput(struct matrix *mat, FILE *in)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    struct matrix matA;

    in=fopen("matrix.txt","r");

    /*Asks for a single character input to name the matrix the user is creating*/
    printf("Enter a single character name for your matrix e.g A,B...\n");
    scanf("%c",&(*mat).name);

    /*Asks for a number of rows of the matrix, valid answers are between and equal to 1 and 10. If these conditions aren't met the program will keep
    prompting for a input that is valid*/
    printf("Enter number of rows in the matrix less than or equal to 10\n");
    scanf("%d",&(*mat).nrows);
    while ((*mat).nrows > 10 || ((*mat).nrows < 1))
    {
        printf("Input is not valid, please enter another number\n");
        scanf("%d",&(*mat).nrows);
    }

    /*Asks for a number of columns of the matrix, valid answers are between and equal to 1 and 10. If these conditions aren't met the program will
    keep prompting for a input that is valid*/
    printf("Enter number of columns in the matrix less than or equal to 10\n");
    scanf("%d",&(*mat).ncols);
    while ((*mat).ncols > 10 || (*mat).ncols < 1)
    {
        printf("Input is not valid, please enter another number\n");
        scanf("%d",&(*mat).ncols);
    }

        for(i=0; i<(*mat).nrows; i++)  //looping for number of rows user has entered
        {
            for(j=0; j<(*mat).ncols;j++)   //looping for number of columns user has entered
            {
                fscanf(in,"%f",&(*mat).mValues[i][j]);  //reading numbers from file and storing them into a 2D array
            }
        }


}


void matrixDisplay(struct matrix mat)
{
    int i,j;



    printf("\nMatrix name: %c  Number of rows are: %d  Number of columns are: %d\n\n",mat.name,mat.nrows,mat.ncols);   //Prints the name of the matrix to screen
    for(i=0; i<mat.nrows;i++)
    {
        printf("Row: %d",(i));
        for(j=0; j<mat.ncols;j++)
        {
            printf("%8.2f",mat.mValues[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}

float matrixDeterminant(struct matrix m1, struct matrix *m2, int *check)
{
    FILE *fin;

    int Rowslim,Colslim,choicecol,choicerow,i,j;


    struct matrix matA;

    struct matrix matB;





    Rowslim=m1.nrows-1;
    Colslim=m1.ncols-1;

    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Please enter a single character name of the 2x2 matrix\n");
    scanf("%c",&(*m2).name);

    printf("Please enter a row number where 2x2 matrix should start, must be between 0 and %d\n",Rowslim);
    scanf("%d",&choicerow);

    printf("please enter a column number where 2x2 matrix should start, must be between 0 and %d\n",Colslim);
    scanf("%d",&choicecol);



    (*m2).nrows=2;
    (*m2).ncols=2;

    fin=fopen("matrix.txt","r");


    {
    for(i=0; i<(choicerow-1); i++)  //looping for number of rows user has entered
        {

            for(j=0; j<(choicecol-1);j++)   //looping for number of columns user has entered
            {
                fscanf(fin,"%f",&(*m2).mValues[i][j]);
            }
            fscanf(fin,"%f",&(*m2).mValues[i][j]);
        }
    }












}
```

Comment: Your "row 2, column 3" is using 1-based array indexes.  That's going to cause confusion; C arrays use 0-based indexes. —— You can, and _should_, write `(*m2).nrows=2;` as `m2->nrows = 2;` — the arrow `->` operator was invented for good reason (and spaces are cheap, but should never be used around the dot `.` or arrow `->` operators).

Comment: The code is meant to take this smaller 2x2 matrix and find the determinant of it and display the smaller matrix to the screen (I haven't added the code to calculate determinant yet sorry for confusion). I was working on trying to get it to display the right matrix. And yes i wanted the smaller matrix to have consecutive rows and columns starting from a position i choose

Comment: Why are you reading a matrix from a file in `matrixDeterminant()` — surely, you need to copy the relevant 2x2 matrix from `m1` into `m2`, placing the result in elements `[0][0]` to `[1][1]`?  That requires no I/O for the matrix data.  As currently configured, you need the input to give the result a name (slightly odd, but OK) and the location.  You really need a function to extract and NxN sub-array from `m1` starting at the given `row` and `col` (column) values.  So: `int matrixExtractSubArray(struct matrix *m2, const struct matrix *m1, char name, int r0, int c0, int size);` _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ The function can report (return) `0` on success; if there's a problem (such as trying to take a sub-array that's out of bounds), it can return -1 (unless you've got an alternative error reporting convention set up).  The coding isn't very difficult while you've got a fixed-size array in the structure.  It gets more fun if you're using variable-size arrays.

Comment: I'm very new to coding so I'm really confused with this aha. How would i write the function to extract the smaller array? The matrix determinant function is meant to ask for a row and column and then based on that extract the smaller matrix from the original matrix created at the beginning (m1)

Comment: Also how would I copy m1 into m2

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I'd use to copy square sub-matrices out of one matrix into a separate matrix:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { MAX_MATRIX_SIZE = 10 };

struct matrix
{
    char name;
    float mValues[MAX_MATRIX_SIZE][MAX_MATRIX_SIZE];
    int nrows;
    int ncols;
};

typedef struct matrix Matrix;

static void matrixDisplay(const Matrix *mat);
static int matrixExtractSubMatrix(Matrix *m2, const Matrix *m1, char name,
                                 int r0, int c0, int size);

int main(void)
{
    Matrix matA =
    {
        .name = 'A', .nrows = 4, .ncols = 4,
        .mValues =
        {
            { 1, 2, 3, 4, }, { 5, 6, 7, 8, },
            { 9, 1, 2, 3, }, { 4, 5, 6, 7, },
        },
    };

    matrixDisplay(&matA);
    Matrix matB;
    for (int i = 0; i < matA.nrows - 2 + 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matA.ncols - 2 + 1; j++)
        {
            if (matrixExtractSubMatrix(&matB, &matA, 'B', i, j, 2) != 0)
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to extract sub-matrix\n");
            matrixDisplay(&matB);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

static void matrixDisplay(const Matrix *mat)
{
    printf("\nMatrix %c (%dx%d):\n", mat->name, mat->nrows, mat->ncols);
    for (int i = 0; i < mat->nrows; i++)
    {
        printf("Row: %d:", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < mat->ncols; j++)
            printf(" %8.2f", mat->mValues[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

static int matrixExtractSubMatrix(Matrix *m2, const Matrix *m1, char name,
                                  int r0, int c0, int size)
{
    assert(m2 != NULL && m1 != NULL);
    assert(r0 >= 0 && r0 + size <= m1->nrows);
    assert(c0 >= 0 && c0 + size <= m1->ncols);
    if ((r0 < 0 || r0 + size > m1->nrows) ||
        (c0 < 0 || c0 + size > m1->ncols))
        return -1;
    m2->name = name;
    m2->nrows = size;
    m2->ncols = size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            m2->mValues[i][j] = m1->mValues[r0 + i][c0 + j];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There's nothing very remarkable about that.  It avoids copying 412 bytes onto the stack by passing the matrix structure as a pointer, not copying the entire structure.  The functions are all `static` except for `main()`.  If functions need to be visible outside this file, they should be declared in a header.  There's no header, so there are no functions (other than `main()`) that need to be visible outside this file.  The dimension of the array in the `Matrix` structure (originally `struct matrix`, but typedef'd to `Matrix` for convenience) is now an enumeration constant so it can be used in the code to designate the maximum dimension of the array in the structure.

I eliminated the file input and the determinant function; the matrix is hard-coded.

The test code prints all the non-wrapping 2x2 sub-matrices:

```
Matrix A (4x4):
Row: 0:     1.00     2.00     3.00     4.00
Row: 1:     5.00     6.00     7.00     8.00
Row: 2:     9.00     1.00     2.00     3.00
Row: 3:     4.00     5.00     6.00     7.00

Matrix B (2x2):
Row: 0:     1.00     2.00
Row: 1:     5.00     6.00

Matrix B (2x2):
Row: 0:     2.00     3.00
Row: 1:     6.00     7.00

Matrix B (2x2):
Row: 0:     3.00     4.00
Row: 1:     7.00     8.00

Matrix B (2x2):
Row: 0:     5.00     6.00
Row: 1:     9.00     1.00

Matrix B (2x2):
Row: 0:     6.00     7.00
Row: 1:     1.00     2.00

Matrix B (2x2):
Row: 0:     7.00     8.00
Row: 1:     2.00     3.00

Matrix B (2x2):
Row: 0:     9.00     1.00
Row: 1:     4.00     5.00

Matrix B (2x2):
Row: 0:     1.00     2.00
Row: 1:     5.00     6.00

Matrix B (2x2):
Row: 0:     2.00     3.00
Row: 1:     6.00     7.00
```

It would be possible to rename that as `matrixExtractSquareSubMatrix()` and create another function `matrixExtractSubMatrix()` which is told separately how many rows and columns to copy:

```
int matrixExtractSubMatrix(Matrix *m2, const Matrix *m1, char name,
                           int r0, int c0, int ncols, int nrows);
```

You might then write `matrixExtractSquareSubMatrix()` as an inline function to call `matrixExtractSubMatrix()` passing the `size` argument twice.

I'm not convinced creating sub-matrices like this is going to be efficient, but that's a subsidiary issue compared with 'correct'.

Comment: Thanks!  The assignment I'm working on is quite confusing but your help is massively appreciated.